# В Android studio нет пункта Java class

Tags: android-studio, java, классы

Нет пункта java class. Начал изучать java под андроид, а в android studio нет пункта Java class.

Что делать?

Вот пункт, как в этом скрине "java class", нету такого!

[image]

Comment: ответ - просто не туда кликаете. Не по имени проекта, а по папке.

Comment: вопрос решен спасибо большое)))

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы это делаете не в папке с кодом, а в какой-то другой, например с ресурсами. Корневая папка для исходного кода выделяется синей иконкой.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -2):

Вероятнее всего, не установил пакеты JDK внутри самой идеи. ) При создании нового проекта укажи путь для JDK - проблема решится.